Timestamp on multiple sheets in one workbook as well update the sheet if another sheet updated the one sheet
I have the following timestamp script in my workbook. The way it is written it is only updating the staff effort sheet.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17-75DRIfKICQYVE2MIUQ7ljZEs4GM-vJXEP4wAXmOgk/edit?usp=sharing
What I would like to have happen is the following.

If  the project list sheet gets edited it will add a time stamp to colunm 22
if the staff effort sheets gets edited, it will add a timestamp to column 12
all other sheets will be ignored

function onEdit(e) {
  let range = e.range;
  let col = range.getColumn()
  let row = range.getRow();
  let sheetName = e.source.getActiveSheet().getName();

  if (sheetName == 'Staff Effort' && col != 50 && row > 12) {
    let timestamp = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),"GMT-5","M/d/yy h:mm a");
    let sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
    sheet.getRange(row,50).setValue(timestamp);
  }
}

function onEdit(e) {
  let range = e.range;
  let col = range.getColumn()
  let row = range.getRow();
  let sheetName = e.source.getActiveSheet().getName();

  if (sheetName == 'Project Tracking' && col != 22 && row > 1) {
    let timestamp = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),"GMT-5","M/d/yy h:mm a");
    let sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
    sheet.getRange(row,22).setValue(timestamp);
  }
}


If I cannot do the on change.  Can I get an example for doing onEdit timestamp for multuple sheets in the same workbook?

I updated my question, based on the feedback that what I was asking could not done in the manor I wanted to do it.

There are many tried and tested timestamping scripts. Try my yetAnotherTimestamp_ script to get started.

I have tried many which is why I am asking here.  I can get it to work one sheet . I can get it to work on all sheets if the column and row are the same on every sheet.  I am having trouble getting it to work on different cells on different sheets in same workbook.   I have spent a lot of time researching and trying it. Was hoping that someone could point me to a reference of this working somewhere..  I am new to app script.

The sample spreadsheet you share isn't publicly editable and can't be copied, so it can't be used for testing. There is a blank sheet maker that lets you share safely.



If the project list sheet gets edited it will add a time stamp to colunm 22
if the staff effort sheets gets edited, it will add a timestamp to column 12
all other sheets will be ignored


You can combine the two onEdit(e) functions like this:
function onEdit(e) {
  const sheet = e.range.getSheet();
  const sheetName = sheet.getName();
  let columnToStamp;
  let rowMin;
  if ('Staff Effort' === sheetName) {
    columnToStamp = 12;
    rowMin = 13;
  } else if ('Project Tracking' === sheetName) {
    columnToStamp = 22;
    rowMin = 2;
  } else {
    return;
  }
  if (e.range.columnStart === columnToStamp) return;
  if (e.range.rowStart < rowMin) return;
  sheet.getRange(e.range.rowStart, columnToStamp)
    .setValue(new Date())
    .setNumberFormat('M/d/yy h:mm a');
}

The question specifies the 'Staff Effort' timestamp column as L (column 12) while the quoted code refers to column AX (column 50). The parameters above stamp column L. To stamp column AX, replace the two occurrences of 12 with 50.
Alternatively, to get better runtime performance and to refer to columns by their labels rather than their ordinals, use my yetAnotherTimestamp_ script with these parameters:
      // [START modifiable parameters]
      {
        sheets: /^(Staff Effort)$/i,
        watch: {
          columns: new Array(100).fill().map((_, i) => columnNumbersToColumnLabels_(1 + i)).filter(c => c !== 'L'),
          values: /./i,
          rowStart: 13,
          rowEnd: +Infinity,
        },
        stamp: {
          columns: new Array(100).fill().map(_ => 'L'),
          format: 'M/d/yy h:mm a',
          overwrite: true,
          eraseOnDelete: false,
        },
      },
      {
        sheets: /^(Project Tracking)$/i,
        watch: {
          columns: new Array(100).fill().map((_, i) => columnNumbersToColumnLabels_(1 + i)).filter(c => c !== 'V'),
          values: /./i,
          rowStart: 2,
          rowEnd: +Infinity,
        },
        stamp: {
          columns: new Array(100).fill().map(_ => 'V'),
          format: 'M/d/yy h:mm a',
          overwrite: true,
          eraseOnDelete: false,
        },
      },
      // [END modifiable parameters]

To stamp 'Staff Effort' column AX, replace the two occurrences of 'L' with 'AX'.


updated on edit via a manual entry or changed due to a formula it will update the designated cell

There is no turnkey way to do that, because formula result changes to not cause any trigger to fire.
Most formulas only refresh when the source data they reference changes, so you could try monitoring edits to that source data instead of monitoring those formula cells.
Alternatively, use a time-driven trigger, and detect changes in a formula cell by comparing its current value to the previous value you retain in the Properties Service.
Note also that when you have multiple onEdit(e) functions in the same script project, only one of them will run. See onEdit(e) best practices.
